# Unable to fetch webpage content from https://play.google.com/store/apps/ programatically on AWS

Tags: google-play, web-crawler, blocking

I have a java application running on AWS EC2 which scrapes app information from https://play.google.com/store/apps/
Everything was running fine until today.
Seems google has started blocking server because of frequent hits.
I tried from another server it was running fine, and that was blocked as well after few hours

Here is my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +appId).timeout(10000).get();
```

I get all page content in doc and parse it.

What should I do to get access?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you have been throttled by google. They do so to block crawler and robots, so you have to limit your calls to google (or contact them to partner with them, but I doubt you want to do so)